# In which browsers is Content-Type: Multipart/X-Mixed-Replace supported?

Tags: comet, multipart-mixed-replace

Please could somebody list the browsers and versions for which the `Content-Type: Multipart/X-Mixed-Replace` is supported for creating an application based on `comet` principles. I have read conflicting accounts of its support in Chrome and Internet Explorer - although some reports mention its inclusion in IE 10.

A follow-up question is, how stable is this technology to build real-time applications? I ask because [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#cite_note-6) currently lists this `Content-Type` as [experimental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#cite_note-6).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The page you link to also answers your question. It is supported in FireFox, Chrome and Safari, but not in IE or in Safari on the iPhone. The page doesn't say anything about IE 10, but since it isn't officially released yet, that makes sense.

According to MSDN, though, IE 10 *does* seem to support [Comet streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Download_streaming_support).

Apart from IE, it has been around for years (since 1995 actually) and should be very stable. The reason why it is marked experimental, is that it isn't declared an official standard yet.

Apparently [Google Analytics](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/01/08/x-mixed-replace.html) already uses this technology and I think they wouldn't if it wasn't stable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I specifically did say browsers and versions, in fact the main thing I'm after is the specific versions of browsers which support the `Content-Type: Multipart/X-Mixed-Replace`. Also if Google Analytics are using this technology I would like to see a reference please! :)

Comment: Well, as you can see, 'Google Analytics' is a link to the page that made the claim. About versions: it was introduced in [Netscape already](http://web.archive.org/web/19981203153836/fishcam.netscape.com/assist/net_sites/pushpull.html), apparently even in [Netscape 1.0](http://www.abiglime.com/webmaster/articles/cgi/032498.htm) meaning that FireFox at least supports it since its first version. Remember that most browsers alive today didn't even exist when this content type was 'invented'.

Comment: Apparently, it was added to [Webkit (Chrome, Safari) by the end of 2005](http://www.stefanseiz.com/archives/2003/06/safari_and_content-type_multipartx-mixed-replace.html).